# SQL query to select one of each kind

Tags: sql

Let's say I have this table:

id colorName
1  red
2  blue
3  red
4  blue

How can I select one representative of each color?
Result:
1 red
2 blue

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Not random representatives, but...

```
select color, min(id)
from   mytable
group by color;
```

Answer (score 15):

In `MS SQL Server` and `Oracle`:

```
SELECT  id, colorName
FROM    (
        SELECT  id, colorName,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colorName ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    colors
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: You need to put an alias name after the parenthesis to get this to work on MS SQL

Comment: @ArjanEinbu, This approach using analytic functions is often far more flexible in practice however, and also easier to debug once queries become more complex.

Comment: @Quassnoi MIN will work with additional fields (`SELECT name, min(id), description FROM color GROUP BY name`) if you're using MySql (at least with 5.7). Whether it should is another matter, but since MySql doesn't support analytic functions until version 8 I'll give them a pass

Comment: @ColinYoung it will, albeit it's not guaranteed from which record will this field be

Comment: @Quassnoi fair enough. MySql has some ... interesting ... ideas about SQL.

Answer (score 14):

```
select distinct colorname from mytable
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT colorName,  
MIN(id) AS id  
FROM table  
GROUP BY colorname
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the easiest way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colorName FROM mytable ORDER BY colorName
```

Answer (score 1):

Although all solutions above are valid in this theoretical 2 column table, if there is a 3rd column, then the aggregate queries (GROUP BY / DISTINCT) will fall short.

For example, if I add a "Fruit" column to the ColorTable

```
alter table #colours add fruit varchar(100)
update #colours set fruit ='strawberry' where id=1
update #colours set fruit ='elderberry' where id=2
update #colours set fruit ='redcurrant' where id=3
update #colours set fruit ='blueberry' where id=4
```

Then use an aggregate query;

```
SELECT colorName,  min(fruit),
MIN(id) AS id  
FROM #colours  
GROUP BY colorname
```

Then the result will show "BlueBerry" on row 2, when it's on row 4.
Using the partition apporach, similar to @Quassnoi then the correct data is returned.

```
    WITH added_row_number AS (
      SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY colorName ORDER BY id) AS row_number
      FROM #colours
    )
    SELECT
      id,colorName,fruit
    FROM added_row_number
    WHERE row_number = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT colorname FROM yourtable ORDER BY id;    *(change id to colorname if desired)*

or

SELECT colorname FROM yourtable GROUP BY colorname;